# When is it appropriate to use a setTimeout vs a Cron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, cron, settimeout

I am building a Meteor application that is using a mongo database.

I have a collection that could potentially have 1000s of documents that need to be updated at different times.

Do I run setTimeouts on creation or a cron job that runs every second and loops over every document?

What are the pros and cons of doing each?

To put this into context:

I am building an online tournament system. I can have 100s of tournaments running which means I could have 1000s of matches.

Each match needs to absolutely end at a specific time, and can end earlier under a condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an OS-level cron job won't work because you can only check with a 60-second resolution. So by "cron job", I think you mean a single `setTimeout` (or [synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron)). Here are some thoughts:

### Single setTimeout

**strategy**: Every second wake up and check a large number of matches, updating those which are complete. If you have multiple servers, you can prevent all but one of them from doing the check via synced-cron.

The advantage of this strategy is that it's straightforward to implement. The disadvantages are:

1. You may end up doing a lot of unnecessary database reads.
2. You have to be **extremely careful** that your processing time does not exceed the length of the period between checks (one second).

I'd recommend this strategy if you are confident that the runtime can be controlled. For example, if you can index your matches on an `endTime` so only a few matches need to be checked in each cycle.

### Multiple setTimeouts

**strategy**: Add a `setTimeout` for each match on creation or when the sever starts. As each timeout expires, update the corresponding match.

The advantage of this strategy is that it potentially removes a considerable amount of unnecessary database traffic. The disadvantages are:

1. It may be a little more tricky to implement. E.g. you have to consider what happens on a server restart.
2. The naive implementation doesn't scale past a single server (see 1).

I'd recommend this strategy if you think you will use a single server for the foreseeable future.

---

Those are the trade-offs which occurred to me given the choices you presented. A more robust solution would probably involve technology outside of the meteor/mongo stack. For example, storing match times in redis and then listening for [keyspace notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications).

Comment: Thanks! I actually was reffering to synced-cron, my bad!
You hit my question right on the mark!

So I went ahead and implemented like you suggeted in timeOuts but the not scaling think could potentially hurt!

I was thinking of using synced cron like this though:
Make a synced cron that runs every x amount of time, set this to when the round is going to end, that only searches for that specific round. when it's done have it delete itself or shut itself off.

aka run multiple synced-crons! Is there a problem with running 1000s of synced crons?

Comment: The short answer is that I don't know, so you should simulate it. Synced-cron is designed to run a few tasks periodically, not a lot of tasks once so it feels like you may be trying to fit a square peg into a round hole. Consider studying how the package works and using only the parts you need - namely an insert which checks for a duplicate key error (see the `SyncedCron._entryWrapper` function).

Comment: Actually, node-cron  (https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) has second granularity instead of minute.

Answer (score 2):

This is all a matter of preference, to be honest with you.

I'm a big fan of writing small, independent programs, that each do one thing, and do it well. If you're also like this, it's probably better to write separate programs to run periodically via cron.

This way you get guaranteed OS-controlled precision for the time, and small, simple programs that are easy to debug outside the context of your webapp.

This is just a preference though.